# application level thread pool and tomcat

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat

Let's say a java application has it's own thread pool to support concurrent task execution and a total of 500 threads are allocated to it. Tomcat is also configured to support an overall 1000 threads via the connector configuration.

Does the connector configuration for 1000 threads act as a superset for the 500 threads application thread pool or are these two independent thread pools? Does this mean a total of 1000 threads are allocated to the deployed application or is it 500 + 1000 = 1500?

Answer (score 0):

When you configure the connector to have max 1000 threads, the connector will have 1000 threads max. It doesn't check how many threads might be active within the same VM.

You don't state how you allocate your custom thread pool, but I've never come across a thread pool that is relating the number of its allowed threads to what else is going on in the system (other than running out of memory).

The reason to your answer would be 1500 then.

It's also easy to find out: Just put your system under the load that it's supposed to handle with 1000 threads and cause a thread dump. When you configure a connector with 1000 threads, you're clearly doing this because you've measured that this is the appropriate size for the volume that you handle, and that implies that you have load tests that can easily generate that load.

And rather than spawning all those threads, I'd like to recommend looking into `java.util.concurrent.Executor` and its relatives.

Comment: I'm using java.util.concurrent library only to create and work with the custom thread pools.

Answer (score 0):

Java's background thread pool is actually re-used by some parts of the base library. So if you for example run a parallelized stream, the exact same thread pool is used for all those streams.

Apache software tends to duplicate the base Java library for reasons beyond me, which means that Tomcat uses its own version of a thread pool that is in no way compatible to or re-using the base library thread pool.

Effectively if you run 500 Java base library thread pool threads and 1000 Tomcat threads, then you are running 1500 threads. And if you take into account that thread switching comes with a small cost, having so many active threads will cause the system to spent a noticeable amount of time on thread-handling instead of executing the actual code. How much exactly completely depends on the internals and the load, but an educated guess for the situation you described would be around 5-15% of CPU time wasted for thread switching.